# GA4 vs UA Dimension, Dimension Filter, and Metric INCOMPATIBILITIES

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Converting GA UA [PHP] code over to GA4 and noticed an incompatibility that was not in UA.

UA query items were ran with following parameters (constructors and such omitted for readability):

```
   $dateRange->setStartDate("31daysAgo");
   $dateRange->setEndDate("today");
   $metric->setExpression("ga:pageviews");
   $dimensions->setName("ga:$region");
   $dimFilter[$i]->setDimensionName("ga:pagePath");
   $dimFilter[$i]->setOperator("PARTIAL");
   $dimFilter[$i]->setExpressions($arrayOfPostIDs[$i]);
```

GA4 equivalent items are:

```
   ->setDateRanges([new DateRange(['start_date' => "31daysAgo",'end_date' => 'today']),])
                
   ->setDimensions([new Dimension(['name' => "$region",]),
                    new Dimension(['name' => 'pagePathPlusQueryString',]),])
               
   ->setMetrics([new Metric(['name' => 'screenPageViews']),])

   ->setDimensionFilter(new FilterExpression([
                            'filter'=> new Filter(['field_name' => 'pagePathPlusQueryString',
                                                   'string_filter' => new StringFilter(['match_type' => MatchType::CONTAINS,
                                                                                        'value' => "$postid",]),]),])
```

UA ga:pagePath included the query string whereas GA4:pagePath does not so have to use the GA4:pagePathPlusQueryString.

The DIM **$region** variable in both UA and GA4 DIM calls would pass in: **'country', 'region', and 'city'** for three separate calls to produce GeoCharts on a customer page.

The StringFilter **$postid** value is an identifier for the customer's posting(s) that will be part of the pagePathPlusQueryString.

UA was able to do those three whereas GA4 can only process 'country'.  This was proven on the GA4 Dim & Metric Explorer as well as the GA4 Query Explorer AND in my code.

**Questions:**

1. Anyone run into something similar and find a work around?
2. Are these INCOMPATs just because they have not been implemented yet OR is it truly a data INCOMPAT with the new way GA4 collects data?

**Thank you,
LarryG**

Comment: The underlying structure of ga4 is completely different than UA don't try to compare them learn the new model

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo .... Thanks Linda for the comment.  Totally understand its apples and oranges but you still have to be able to extract the same/similar data.  My point was ... if I can choose a DIM of 'country' to get GA4 pageView data, and IT WORKS then one would think using other available Geo DIMs (ie 'region' and 'city' for instance) would provide pageView data with those DIMs.  Am simply pointing out what could be BUGS vs INCOMPAT.   The documentation on all this is severly lacking and the paint is definitely still wet! :-p